# What are potential hashing algorithms for strings in pure Python?

Tags: python, hash

The standard `hash('hello')` function may generate different hashes on different machines, different versions of Python, and even different runs of the same program on the same Python version/machine.

What are decent *pure Python* (or built in) alternatives that have low chances of collision? The use case I'm after is checking uniqueness of a string in a database (note: it doesn't have to be 100% foolproof, just extremely unlikely to collide with another string).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

Comment: This might help: http://www.pythoncentral.io/hashing-strings-with-python/

Comment: Note: the "duplicate" question only discusses C solutions, not pure Python. I will probably go with `hashlib` but was hoping to also find other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

[Murmurhash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) is a good bet for non-cyrptographic uses (as opposed to [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html), which uses slow crypto-hashes), for a variety of reasons:

- very widely used
- portable across not only Python versions and machines, but across different languages

[Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/murmurhash3/2.3.5) is its Python bindings. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057036/please-explain-murmur-hash) is a question on the algorithm itself.

---

If, for some technical reason, a pure-Python roll-your-own implementation might be needed, there are a few feasible options:

- the source code for murmurhash is in the first link above, but, in pure Python mode, should probably be replaced by something simpler
- immediate candidates are the [Knuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871245/knuth-multiplicative-hash) and [Jenkins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a package for it that will run in an environment that doesn't allow C modules?

Comment: I'm not sure. What is an "enviornment that doesn't allow C modules": a technical or organizational environment? It depends...

Comment: App Engine runs (I believe) a modified version of pypy with a lot of restrictions due to their sandbox. Basically, I can't run anything compiled, it has to be written entirely in Python.

Comment: See update. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how they compare to FNV-1a in terms of random distribution and collision rates?

Answer (score 1):

Try the python hashlib. It has implementations of MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512 which should give you a good hash with low chance of collision.

Example Input:

```
import hashlib
hashed_string = hashlib.sha512("hello").hexdigest()
print hashed_string
```

Output:

```
9b71d224bd62f3785d96d46ad3ea3d73319bfbc2890caadae2dff72519673ca72323c3d99ba5c11d7c7acc6e14b8c5da0c4663475c2e5c3adef46f73bcdec043
```

Comment: Note that these are cryptographic & slow hashes. The OP's question is to the default ``hash`` which is in a different domain.

Comment: I'm not going to be doing thousands of these per second so I think `hashlib` will do, but yes I would have preferred to find a pure Python solution that was not cryptographic. I'll also look into Murmurhash.