# Murmur Hash simple flowchart?

Tags: hash, flowchart, murmurhash

I found [MurmurHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash#Algorithm) recently as one of the [fastest](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed), and MurmurHash3 is the new version of MurmurHash.
I also found the complete explanation of [MurmurHash in a Diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057036/please-explain-murmur-hash) by Ian Boyd.
This diagram really looks awesome but I understand only a bit of it since I'm still a newbie and have interest in Hashing.

It would be very helpful if someone could help me with a *simple* **MurmurHash3 Flowchart**.

Since I'm a newbie and still can't add any comment [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057036/please-explain-murmur-hash), I also don't know how to contact Ian Boyd either, I'm trying to ask it here..

**update**
I made my own MurmurHash3 flowchart. 
Will upload it later

I'm sorry for my noobness and bad in English. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I know I am reply late, but it may help any one else... 
**Murmur hashing** is a non cryptographic [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) 
which is used for [hash based look-ups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) , it uses 3 basic operations as a whole [Multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication), [Rotate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift) and [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). It uses multiple constants which are just there to make it good hash function by passing 2 basic tests.

1. [Avalanche Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect)
2. [Chi-Squared Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test)

You can watch  [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8HzEZt0RCQ&t) video, which I made, for the detail explanation of Murmur Hashing.

Comment: Thank you sir! It short but well explained.